# Unable to start a WebDriver session in protractor for Appium

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, protractor, cucumber, appium

I've been trying to set up a Protractor-Cucumber framework where I am planning to include appium features. For that, I'm currently trying to connect my android device to the visual studio code with Typescript language. But after starting my appium server and running the npm script, I am getting the below error.

```
> protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0 test C:\Users...\Documents\autobots-protractor
> protractor typeScript/config/config.js
[12:51:39] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:51:39] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
[12:51:51] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[12:51:51] E/launcher - Error: UnsupportedOperationError: Not implemented yet for script.
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\...\Documents\autobots-protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\...\Documents\autobots-protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\...\Documents\autobots-protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[12:51:51] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

*My config file looks like this:*

```
const phone ={
    browserName: '',
    platformName: 'Android',
    platformVersion:'10', 
    deviceName: 'xyz',
    app:'C:\\Users\\....\\Documents\\autobots-protractor\\App\\LGCalculator.apk', 
    appPackage: 'com.android.calculator2',
    appActivity:'com.android.calculator2.Calculator', 
    udid: 'SFD3Y184ahsdcj24', 
    automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
}
export const config: Config = {
 seleniumAddress:"http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",baseUrl:"https://www.google.com",
    multiCapabilities:[phone],
    framework: "custom",
    frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),

    specs: [
        "../../features/*.feature",
    ],
services:{
        appium: {
        waitStartTime: 6000,
        waitforTimeout: 30 * 60000,
        command: 'appium',
        logFileName: 'appium.log',
        args: {
            address: 'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub',
            port: 4723,
            commandTimeout: 30 * 60000,
            sessionOverride: true,
            debugLogSpacing: true,
                },
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: could you please share the full appium server Log

Comment: Please find the appium log for reference. Link:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jXM7RR--HONaYY_inBmoK6rtCE5nlx2s

Comment: Tihs is not accessible to me

Answer (score 1):

please refer [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13679)
issue, I was having the same now its working fine, or may some typo could be there. Please share the full Appium server log

Comment: indeed this was a typo from my side in multi capabilities now it's working as expected.